# Optimizing indexes on long MySql query

Tags: mysql, performance, indexing

Sorry I couldn't be more specific in the title.

So I got this query:

```
CREATE TABLE RecordPoints AS (
SELECT competitionId, personId, personCountryId, eventId, year, date,
if(regionalAverageRecord = 'WR',
(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT personId) FROM ResultDates rd
WHERE rd.eventId=rd2.eventId AND rd.date <= rd2.date AND rd.average > 0), 0) wrAveragePoints,
if(regionalSingleRecord = 'WR',
(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT personId) FROM ResultDates rd
WHERE rd.eventId=rd2.eventId AND rd.date <= rd2.date), 0) wrSinglePoints,
if(NOT regionalAverageRecord in('WR', 'NR'),
(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT personId) FROM ResultDates rd
WHERE rd.eventId=rd2.eventId AND rd.date <= rd2.date AND average > 0 AND rd.personCountryId in
(SELECT Countries.id FROM Countries JOIN Continents on Countries.continentId=Continents.id where recordName = rd2.regionalAverageRecord)), 0) crAveragePoints,
if(NOT regionalAverageRecord in('WR', 'NR'),
(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT personId) FROM ResultDates rd
WHERE rd.eventId=rd2.eventId AND rd.date <= rd2.date AND rd.personCountryId in
(SELECT Countries.id FROM Countries JOIN Continents on Countries.continentId=Continents.id where recordName = rd2.regionalSingleRecord)), 0) crSinglePoints,
if(regionalAverageRecord = 'NR',
(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT personId) FROM ResultDates rd
WHERE rd.eventId=rd2.eventId AND rd.date <= rd2.date AND rd.personCountryId=rd2.personCountryId AND rd.average > 0 ), 0) nrAveragePoints,
if(regionalSingleRecord = 'NR',
(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT personId) FROM ResultDates rd
WHERE rd.eventId=rd2.eventId AND rd.date <= rd2.date AND rd.personCountryId=rd2.personCountryId), 0) nrSinglePoints
FROM ResultDates rd2 WHERE (NOT regionalAverageRecord='' OR NOT regionalSingleRecord = ''));
```

And it took 9 hours to finish. To break it down, I'm creating a table where 6 of the columns are entire sub queries to count up how many times a personId appears in the same table before the first thing I'm looking at happened based on the date and a few other columns. 
Creating an index on date using `CREATE INDEX date ON ResultDates (date)` sped it up a little I think but it still takes a monsterous amount of time.

The rows in `ResultDates` look like

```
+------------+-----------------+---------------+---------+---------+-----+---------+----------------------+-----------------------+-------+-----+------+------------+
| personId   | personCountryId | competitionId | eventId | roundId | pos | average | regionalSingleRecord | regionalAverageRecord | month | day | year | date       |
+------------+-----------------+---------------+---------+---------+-----+---------+----------------------+-----------------------+-------+-----+------+------------+
| 1982THAI01 | USA             | WC1982        | 333     | f       |   1 |       0 | WR                   |                       |     6 |   5 | 1982 | 1982-06-05 |
+------------+-----------------+---------------+---------+---------+-----+---------+----------------------+-----------------------+-------+-----+------+------------+
```

Where regionalSingleRecord and regionalAverageRecord can be any of these "RecordNames": WR, NR, nothing most of the time, or AfR, AsR, ER, NAR, OcR, or SAR which I then use to look up a countryId based on what continent those recordNames are connected to.

I have created indexes to connect those recordNames to continents and continent ids to countryIds, not sure how much this improved the speed though.

Running EXPLAIN on it returns me this:

```
+----+--------------------+------------+------------+------+-------------------+--------------+---------+----------------------------------+--------+----------+---------------------------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type        | table      | partitions | type | possible_keys     | key          | key_len | ref                              | rows   | filtered | Extra                                                         |
+----+--------------------+------------+------------+------+-------------------+--------------+---------+----------------------------------+--------+----------+---------------------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY            | rd2        | NULL       | ref  | idx_personId      | idx_personId | 32      | const                            |    567 |    99.00 | Using where                                                   |
|  9 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | rd         | NULL       | ALL  | date,idx_personId | NULL         | NULL    | NULL                             | 992294 |     0.33 | Range checked for each record (index map: 0x3)                |
|  8 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | rd         | NULL       | ALL  | date,idx_personId | NULL         | NULL    | NULL                             | 992294 |     0.11 | Range checked for each record (index map: 0x3)                |
|  6 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | Continents | NULL       | ref  | P_id,recordIndex  | recordIndex  | 9       | cubing.rd2.regionalSingleRecord  |      1 |   100.00 | Using index; Start temporary                                  |
|  6 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | Countries  | NULL       | ALL  | NULL              | NULL         | NULL    | NULL                             |    203 |    10.00 | Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop)            |
|  6 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | rd         | NULL       | ALL  | date              | NULL         | NULL    | NULL                             | 992294 |     0.33 | Range checked for each record (index map: 0x1); End temporary |
|  4 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | Continents | NULL       | ref  | P_id,recordIndex  | recordIndex  | 9       | cubing.rd2.regionalAverageRecord |      1 |   100.00 | Using index; Start temporary                                  |
|  4 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | Countries  | NULL       | ALL  | NULL              | NULL         | NULL    | NULL                             |    203 |    10.00 | Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop)            |
|  4 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | rd         | NULL       | ALL  | date              | NULL         | NULL    | NULL                             | 992294 |     0.11 | Range checked for each record (index map: 0x1); End temporary |
|  3 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | rd         | NULL       | ALL  | date,idx_personId | NULL         | NULL    | NULL                             | 992294 |     3.33 | Range checked for each record (index map: 0x3)                |
|  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | rd         | NULL       | ALL  | date,idx_personId | NULL         | NULL    | NULL                             | 992294 |     1.11 | Range checked for each record (index map: 0x3)                |
+----+--------------------+------------+------------+------+-------------------+--------------+---------+----------------------------------+--------+----------+---------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I've been doing some googling on how to improve the speed of it. Based on my googling, I know it doesn't look good. Especially with the 992294 rows that is in my initial table I'm looking at.

My problem though is that I don't know how to go about optimizing to make all of this faster. I've read that carefully crafted indexes can improve speed by a lot so I'm curious what kind of indexes can be used here.

Answer (score 0):

Subqueries in select clauses can be very costly. Correlated subqueries in general are poor performers and generally have better alternatives.

I don't have time to give a thorough answer, but my general impression from skimming the query is you can probably refactor it to JOIN ResultDates to itself, once, in the main query; and then use conditional aggregation in the SELECT clause. Something like this...

```
SELECT rd.competitionId, rd.personId, rd.personCountryId, rd.eventId
   , rd.year, rd.date
   , COUNT(DISTINCT IF(rd.regionalAverageRecord = 'WR' AND rdPrev.average > 0, rdPrev.person_id, NULL) AS wrAveragePoints
   , COUNT(DISTINCT IF(regionalSingleRecord = 'WR', rdPrev.person_id, NULL) AS wrSinglePoints
   , [etc....]
FROM ResultDates AS rd 
LEFT JOIN ResultDates AS rdPrev 
   ON rd.eventId=rdPrev.eventId 
   AND rdPrev.date <= rd.date
WHERE (NOT rd.regionalAverageRecord='' OR NOT rd.regionalSingleRecord = '')
;
```

Edit: For the subqueries/fields involving the `Countries` and `Continents` tables, you may be able to just `LEFT JOIN` to those tables as well and use the joined values in a manner similar to how I demonstrated `rdPrev.average` being used in the `wrAveragePoints` calculation.

Note: `COUNT()` and most other aggregation functions ignore NULL values.